# Neural network: noisy temporal sequence converter (transducer?producer?) on demand?

Tags: formal-languages, neural-networks

I start to suspect this problem is very hard now that I cannot find a single relevant literature on the subject, but it's too late to change the class project topics now, so I hope any pointers to a solution. Please pardon the somewhat artificial scenerio of this question, but here goes:

Technical version:

Let $\Sigma_{c}$ and $\Sigma_{q}$ and $\Sigma_{a}$ be 3 disjoint finite alphabet (c, q, a stand for content, query and answer respectively). Let $L_{c}\in\Sigma_{c}^{*}$ and $L_{q}\in\Sigma_{q}^{*}$ be FINITE languages, wherein $L_{q}$ have the property that for every string in the language all of its prefix are in the language too. There is an unknown function $f:L_{c}\times L_{q}\rightarrow\Sigma_{a}^{*}$. Consider a mysterious machine that receive continuous stream of symbol through a channel one at a time step (we assume that the symbol are clearly distinguishable). This machine, whenever being feed with a string in $c\in L_{c}$ (with the symbol in correct temporal order) followed by a string in $q\in L_{q}$ will output (through a different output channel) the value of $f(c,q)$ as a temporal sequence, one symbol at a time. Note that the machine always output after every new symbol from $\Sigma_{q}$. Note that the empty string is in $L_{q}$, which means the machine also output something before any symbol on $\Sigma_{q}$ have arrived, but only if it is certain with high probability that the full string in $L_{c}$ have been received.

The objective is to construct a neural network that emulate that mysterious machine, if we have only access to its input and output channel to use as training data, and we do not know $f$. We also have to assume that the input channel are noisy in the following sense: random noise are inserted into the input channel at high probability, delaying input symbol, and we initially do not know which one is noise and which one is authentic; also symbol in the input channel are sometimes lost at low probability. EDIT: Note: we do not know $L_{c}$ nor $L_{q}$, only the mysterious machine know, in fact we do not even know the alphabet $\Sigma_{c}$ and $\Sigma_{q}$ other than the fact that they are disjoint and are subset of the set of all possible input symbol (input symbol not in either set are certainly noise, but we can't tell which set it belongs to initially; note that it is still possible for symbol from the alphabet to be noise).

(why neural network: beside the noise problem, also because that's what I wrote in my class project proposal)

(layman version: consider Sherlock Holmes sitting in his chair, bored. Dr. Watson give a short description of the client. Once he's done, Sherlock Holmes give a conclusion about the client. Dr. Watson is astonished, and ask more question, and Sherlock Holmes reply. The conclusion must obviously based on the description alone; and subsequent answer have to answer the question being asked, taking into account the contexts which consists of question already being asked (for example, the same "How did you know?" following "Age?" demands different answer than when following "Height?"). Now you want to make a neural network that simulate Sherlock Holmes, having all the recordings of those session. Dr. Watson however tend to insert in long description that are rather irrelevant, making long statement before finally getting around to ask question, and sometimes accidentally omit crucial information, but otherwise describe people in a rather fixed order of details. The neural network must be able to deal with that. Of course, this is a just a layman's description, the situation is much less complex.)

I have looked through various relevant literature, and I cannot find anything relevant. Conversion to spatial domain is useless due to high amount of noise causing very long input sequence. I have looked into LSTM to deal with the memory problem over arbitrary long time lag, but I for the life of me cannot figure out how is the network is supposed to be trained when there are arbitrarily long noise insertion everywhere or possibilities of missing symbol (every method I found seems to force a fixed time-lag between input and output, and missing symbol immediately wreck any method based on predicting the next item in the sequence). Also, is it too much to ask for network that isn't too hard to code? Integrate-and-fire neuron is even worse than LSTM in term of difficulty in coding.

Thanks for your help. It's due in 2 days, so please be fast.

Comment: Maybe you should give your age and class level on your personal page,
so that people might have a chance to know what kind of work may be
expected from your project.

Comment: Ah sorry but I am nothing more than a mere undergraduate taking an AI class, nothing big.

Comment: Nothing to be sorry about. Often, it just helps answering. I found your question rather articulate, compared to many others ... but I fear you are aiming too far ... and with very little time.

Comment: Some thoughts on noise and empty queries: since $L_c$ is finite, it is in principle possible to check a) whether or not some arriving Symbol complements the current input to a String in the Language and b) what the permissible continuations of a current Input String in $L_c$ Are, including the cardinality of the set. Based ob b) you can decide whether 'Content' Input is complete with sufficient confidence (maybe including the threshold in the set of trained parameters), a) detects noise in the best but possible way and will aid you in determining the end of noise. More sophisticated schemes...

Comment: ...will require more information (e.g. The noise Statistics, characteristics of $f$, statistics on $L_c$). In General, noise will not harm the training result when offset by additional Training Data unless noise produces false positives. Again, as $L_c$ and $\Sigma_c$ are finite and 'usually' a content string will be delimited, critical items from the training set can principally be detected and might be handled in a special way (eg. In a first approximation by dropping them).

Comment: @collapsar: I fixed the question. I should have mentioned that we do not even know what constitute the alphabet of either languages, much less than languages themselves. Finiteness is just to ensure pigeon hole on sufficiently large amount of data. Sorry for the omission.

Comment: Are the Outputs synchronized with the Input ?

Comment: @collapsar: each set of data time stamp every symbol in each channel, if that's what you are asking. So you can always tell exactly what symbol arrived on input and channeled through output at any specific time.

Comment: @Desperado no, if your input arrives One Symbol a Time and the Output is generated, without Information on $Im(f)$ (eG. Lengths of Output vs. Input words) you have no Information which Part of the Output Stream Relates to which Part of the input Stream. Just imagine a sequence of Inputs with empty Query and Output words that are longer than the corresponding input words.

Comment: @collapsar: then I do not get your question. I will just make a simple example here. Let's say $L_{c}={ABC}$ and $L_{q}={\epsilon,0,01}$ and $f(ABC,\epsilon)=DA;f(ABC,0)=CBA;f(ABC,01)=BB$. Then given this input stream with noise "XFAB0DCT1UJJDH0GG1AG" then output stream is  "~~~~~~~DA~~~~~~CBABB" where "~" means nothing is output (but still take 1 time step). So "D" is output 1 time step after input "C" (ie. upon completion of "ABC"), "CBA" is output 1 time step after "0", and "BB" should have been output 1 time step after input "1" but is delayed due to "CBA" still being output.

Comment: @Desperado consider $f(x,\epsilon)=DD...(n \text{times})...D, x \in \{A, B, C\}, f(y,\epsilon)=DD...(2*n \text{times})...D, y \in \{AB, AC, BC\}$ - how do you segment the input stream ?

Answer (score 2):

I unfortunately know very little of neural network.  The closest thing
that your project reminds me of is speech recognition, and I would
look at that literature. I am thinking of the first stage of speech
recognition, when the sound stream is transformed into a word lattice
(or a word stream, if you keep only the most likely path in the
lattice). But all I know on this is based on Hidden Markov Models and
Viterbi algorithm [1]. I have not looked at the field for a long time, and
I have no idea how it would translate in neural network, but I would
suggest you look at that literature, for example by searching the web
for *neural networks* and *speech recognition*.

I doubt you can code anything serious in 2 days. I would not even try,
but  I do not know what kind of programming is expected. But maybe a good
description of what should be done, with appropriate references would
be enough.

You should simplify your question, if you find out that your
requirements are too strong, particularly on noise. At first, you
should limit yourself to very simple kinds of noise. Problems are
seldom solved the first time in full complexity. You first solve simple cases, then
try to see where you could do more. For one thing, do you know how to
do it without any noise? What are the limitations? Then you can start
adding simple noise, and see what changes.

Your input, content and query, do not seem to have much reason to be
distinguished, or do you have a strong reason to distinguish them?
I would think that at some point your system must enter a state when
it starts answering on the output tape.

[1] Bahl, L. R.,Jelinek, F., & Mercer,R.L. (1983).A maximum likelihood approach tocontinuous speech recognition. IEEETrans. Pattern Anal. Machine Intell., PAMI 5, 179-190.

These authors actually published several papers on the subject for noisy input, including insertion, deletion and substitution of symbols. There are surely others, and this work is quite old. I am not sure the paper referenced is actually about learning. But the same people worked on learning too, such as parameters identification for Hidden Markov Models.

Comment: I already looked at that particular paper, and a few other having to do with speech recognition, but nothing there seems to convince me that it works also on long range noise (ie. lots of noise inserted).  Oh and about reason to distinguish query, it is because the network is not supposed to answer until the query is given, and that could be very late. From my understanding, gradient-based training will enforced a fixed time lag between input and output, so would fail utterly if a query is too late. I just need something just work good enough to pass this class. Didn't realize it is this hard.

Comment: If neural network is your choice, rather than a constraint from your
instructor, you can justify switching to another approach just by
explaining why, after studying the literature, you came to the
conclusion that the other approach would be better suited. BTW, if you
are late, but can show you have been working, it is sometimes possible
to negotiate time ... depending on instructor and local policy.

Comment: Regarding your problem, the normal way to proceed is to check what
simpler problem is already solved (to whatever extent) in the
published literature. For example: is there a way to do it if $L_c$
and/or $L_q$ are known, or their alphabet, and/or if you have no
noise, or no noise on some parts of the input ... whatever simplifies
things. Then starting from there, adding one single source of
complexity is already a lot for an undergraduate project. Have you
done that? Could it be that one way to deal with the time lag problem
is to signal the boundary between content and query noiselessly.